# NSURLConnection: I'm trying to receive html page, but always get error 403

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, server-error

I want to get html page and parse it.

I send to http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=u_dAYLIG984

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString: fullPath];

NSMutableDictionary* headers = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
[headers setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8" forKey:@"Content-Type"];
[headers setValue:@"text/html" forKey:@"Accept"];
[headers setValue:@"no-cache" forKey:@"Cache-Control"];
[headers setValue:@"no-cache" forKey:@"Pragma"];
[headers setValue:@"close" forKey:@"Connection"];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:TIMEOUT_REQUEST];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:delegate startImmediately:YES];
```

I always get 403 error. What is wrong ?

EDITED:

I tried my request on http://bbc.co.uk/ and it works well. My problem only with http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=u_dAYLIG984

EDITED2:

@Christophe Debove, you are right. I changed my request from POST to GET and received 406 error. It became working when I deleted "Accept" header. It works even without google developer key.

Comment: HTTP is HTTP if it work within a browser and If you check your header values it must work regardless the device, so if with your browser you does't need google developper key it's the same. be aware  some webapp as google calendar ask you a captcha if you'are not using the api way, after multiple request from the same ip. Be sure you tube never ask you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems server forbid you. It can happen when you forget to pass security parameters or you're wrong with some headers values.

```
HTTP code 403   Forbidden
```

I try to send the request with [LiveHTTPHeader](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) the firefox module.
And I saw youtube api doesn't accept POST request but only GET.

When I send with `POST` method I get `403 forbiden Target feed is read-only`

So please change the method with `GET`

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```

you can remove some of your headers value even if they don't cause the pb there are useless.

Comment: I added headers but it doesn't helped me. The problem is only for http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos

Comment: Do you add the header or replace? you must replace

Comment: thank you for help. I replaced the header, but I need a google developer key. I found it http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html

Comment: @Voloda, Ok Great, when you will be able to please add your solution as answer to provide it to other user.

Comment: I added google developer key but problem still exists. I will signal when I find the solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a pb with the headers values you send I don't understand why you send Content Type Key, Please see my edit